# Calling function in addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying two ways to implement this situaiton: when a `test-button` is clicked, a text `Hello World` is displayed at `<p>` element `test-text`

***Method 1***

```
function showText(test_button_id) {
    let test_text = document.getElementById("test-text")
    test_text.innerText = "Hello World";

}

let test_button = document.getElementById("test-button")
test_button.addEventListener('click', showText('test-button'))
```

***Method 2***

```
let test_button = document.getElementById("test-button")
let test_text = document.getElementById("test-text")

test_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        test_text.innerText = "Hello World";
})
```

Method 2 works. Method 1 does not. What is wrong with the way I am calling the function in `addEventListener`? I know the argument `test_button_id` is not doing anything in this code. I intend to parse it in if the code works. Thanks.

Comment: addEventListener requires a function as the handler argument, not the result of calling a function - you could do `test_button.addEventListener('click', () => showText('test-button'))`

Comment: @JaromandaXI don't quite understand the difference. Could I trouble for you for more explanation or pointing to some documentation on JavaScript? I am a newbie in JS.

Comment: addEventListener function argument is only his name, as address, and this function must have only the event as argument

Comment: `fn()` calls a function ... `fn` does not